# Should android resource id's be used for non-layout code?

Tags: android, resources, unique-key

The android resource [ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) is often used as a way to get/modify an XML-defined layout component.  Is it acceptable to use them purely as unique identifiers for any Java code in your Android application? For example:

### Using Android Resource IDs

**ids.xml**

```
<item name="sensor_pressure" type="id"/>
<item name="sensor_humidity" type="id"/>
<item name="sensor_precision_gas" type="id"/>
```

**Sensor.java**

```
public Sensor(int sensorId) {
    initializeSensor(sensorId);
}

private void determineSensorType(int sensorId) {
    switch(sensorId) {
    case R.id.sensor_pressure:
        intializePressureSensor();
        break;
    case R.id.sensor_humidity:
        initializeHumiditySensor();
        break;
    // etc...
    }
}
```

---

Or would it be preferable to do things in pure Java? For example:

### Using Only Java

**Sensor.java**

```
public Sensor(int sensorId) {
    initializeSensor(sensorId);
}

enum SensorType {
    PRESSURE, HUMIDITY, PRECISION_GAS
}

private void determineSensorType(SensorType sensorType) {
    switch(sensorType) {
    case SensorType.PRESSURE:
        intializePressureSensor();
        break;
    // etc...
    }
}
```

### ***Best Solution For My Example:***

From MaciejGórski below.  Using an interface, one can solve the problem posed by ridding of the need of unique IDs completely.

```
public interface Sensor {

}

public class HumiditySensor implements Sensor {

    public HumiditySensor() {
        init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an object oriented way?

```
public interface Sensor {

}

public class HumiditySensor implements Sensor {

    public HumiditySensor() {
        init();
    }
}
```

You can avoid having ugly switch statements in many places in your code.

Comment: I agree, Will be far cleaner that way. I'll update my post to include this example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable to use them purely as unique identifiers for any Java code in your Android application?

It certainly works, but...

> Or would it be preferable to do things in pure Java?

I'd go with this approach. If nothing else, the `enum` prevents you from getting your identifiers mixed up with other integers.

Comment: I'm not a wiz on Java's internals but, out of curiosity, are there any pros/cons in terms of execution speed?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly doable, but I can't think of a single benefit of putting some kind of contants/ids in a resource file. Using enums allow you to group related constants and it helps you avoid accidentally mixing unrelated constants.